# python: how to show multiple images from data frame directory column?

Tags: python

I have data frame with image directory (example "Desktop/myfiles/data/car333.jpg") I'm my folder have cars and train pictures I'm trying to display 12 pictures 6 cars and 6 trains I'm stuck here and not sure how to approach this problem

```
plt.figure()
x,ax = plt.subplots(3,4) 
for z in mydata["myimages"]:
     if "car" in z:
      #ax.imshow(mpimg.imread(z))
    else:
        #ax.imshow(mpimg.imread(z))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this answer for the post you have just deleted.

```
b = {}  # dictionary to hold images with filenames as keys
plt.figure()
a, im = plt.subplots(4, 6)  # returns grid of axes to im
for i, z in enumerate(mydata["imageName"]):
    if i >= im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]:
        break  # breaking from loop if you have more filenames than images in grid
    b[z] = im[i // im.shape[1]][i % im.shape[1]]  # assign axes to dictionary by key (filename)
    if z.startswith("car"):
        image_ = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(my_path, z))
        b[z].imshow(image_)
    else:
        image_ = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(my_path1, z))
        b[z].imshow(image_)

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you please explain how b[z].imshow(image_) work I thought z is suppose to be an index ?

Comment: im holds a grid of axes (4 * 6), and z is a key in dictionary b. I've assigned each of the grid axes to the specific dictionary entry with b[z] = im[i // im.shape[1]][i % im.shape[1]] (e.g. if i is 15 and I divide 15 by 6, where s is shape[1] of the grid, I get 2 for portions and 3 for leftover so b[z] = im[2][3])

Answer (score 0):

You can get two subsets
subset1=car, subset=train

then pass them to this function

```
def imdisp(subset):
    flist=subset.values.tolist() #if needed
    
    for i in flist
        im=mpimg.imread(z)
        fig.add_subplot(3,2, i)
        plt.imshow(im)
        
    plt.show()
```